# react code splitting: is the argument for the import() function not a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, code-splitting

This is very bizarre. During my attempt at code-splitting, I encountered this:

```
const g = "bi";
const importStr = `react-icons/${g.toLowerCase()}`;
console.log(importStr);
console.log(importStr === `react-icons/bi`);

import(importStr).then(module => {
    console.log(module);
});



import(`react-icons/bi`).then(module => {
    console.log(module);

});
```

In the above code, if I import "importStr", then the import throws an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module 'react-icons/bi'

But if I directly import "react-icons/bi", then there is no issue. As you see,

```
importStr === `react-icons/bi`
```

Why and how do I fix this? I can't actually directly use "react-icons/bi" because g is dynamic and could take other values.

Comment: This gets run through a bundler? It might not be able to compute `importStr` properly.

Comment: That may be the reason. But how can I dynamically import 'react-icons/bi' or 'react-icons/fa' or any other subgroups of icons depending on the needs?

Comment: That will depend on your bundler, what are you using? Webpack? Rollup? Parcel?

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you wrap your import by function like `function work(str) { import(str).then(console.log) }` and then call it ```work(`react-icons/${g.toLowerCase()}`);```

Comment: webpack. The app was created using "create react app"

Comment: @EduardJacko Tried what you suggested but still got the same error.             
```
function work(str) {
    import(str).then(module => {
                    console.log(module);
                });
            };


work(`react-icons/${g.toLowerCase()}`);
```

Comment: try this https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6680#issuecomment-370800037

Comment: basically `import("react-icons/" + g)`

Comment: @EduardJacko This is right on point! I tried "import("react-icons/" + g.toLowerCase())" and that for some reason didn't work, which I suspect is specific to react-icons (got the Error "Module not found: Can't resolve './iconBase' in '/Users/myusername/Projects/myproject/node_modules/react-icons/src'" despite that the import should be from icon bundles such as "bi" and "fa", not from "src"), but when I tried "import("react-icons/" + g.toLowerCase()+ '/index.js')" that worked! Would you write up the gist of your solution, so that I can accept your answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quote from the following [comment](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6680#issuecomment-370800037)

> Webpack performs a static analyse at build time. It doesn't try to infer variables which that import(test) could be anything, hence the failure. It is also the case for import(path+"a.js").

Because of the tree shaking feature webpack tries to remove all unused code from the bundle. That also means something similar could work

```js
import("react-icons/" + g)
```

Edit: as per your suggestion I updating this to

```js
import("react-icons/" + g.toLowerCase()+ '/index.js')
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to implement code splitting in React is with lazy loading, as seen here (this might be easier than importing a dynamic string):

```
const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));
```

This implementation will load the bundle with `OtherComponent` only when it is first rendered.

Example from reactjs.org:

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));
const AnotherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./AnotherComponent'));

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <section>
          <OtherComponent />
          <AnotherComponent />
        </section>
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[More info on React.lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy)

Comment: I think his issue is dynamic import paths where he is not able to build path from variables.